# How can I remove a vanity backsplash without damaging ceramic tile?

Tags: adhesive, ceramic-tile, backsplash

My bathroom vanity has a backsplash that is firmly glued to ceramic tile. I believe that liquid nails or something similar was used for adhesive. I have tried prying with a putty knife and going around the edge with a box knife.

Is there a good way to remove the basksplash without damaging the tile?

[image: vanity basksplash on ceramic tile]

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? If a previous owner installed it, there might be a good reason, like holes or damaged tile.

Comment: I want to install a new vanity. It was installed under my tenure here. There's nothing unusual behind it. I just didn't have 100% certainty on the type of adhesive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acetone is great for dissolving glue and adhesive. Try pouring some along the top of the backsplash and let it soak in between the wall and backsplash. After about 15 minutes try to pry it gently with a mud knife, looking for a little loosening of the backsplash. Apply more acetone as needed. Good luck.

Comment: The acetone worked like a charm. Thanks all for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

A "cheese cutting wire" is a classic way to approach this problem. Thin, strong wire with handles so you can pull it through, cutting the adhesive as you go.

Comment: So you carry a garrote in your toolbox?+

Answer (score 0):

The backsplash may be attached with some type of silcone sealant/adhesive.  I don't acetone will touch cured silicone.  I would try to work a thin putty knife down behind the backsplash and the tiles.

Comment: yes, or a fine steel wire or cable.